# vb.net how to remove this script tag?

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to remove this script tag in vb.net?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d2nasxlktxv6tm.cloudfront.net/webclient-next/manifest-5d1034b834d8851f0991.js"></script>
```

I've tried with this code, but still no luck.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        For Each ele As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
            If ele.OuterHtml.Contains("https://d2nasxlktxv6tm.cloudfront.net/webclient-next/manifest-5d1034b834d8851f0991.js") Then
                ele.OuterHtml = ""
            End If

        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not?  If you're checking the source it won't show up as being deleted there.  Also, I would use something like this: WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("script") vs document.all to narrow the results.

Comment: @NathanChampion, yes tried with it already as well with WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("script"), it seems to be be able to remove it, even check it with .InnerText, no luck :(

Comment: Well, the inner text will return an empty string.  It's not going to stop that script from firing initially if that's the issue.